# JRadioButton setMnemonic broken Java 1.5

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, java-5

I am attempting to convert a short JComboBox to a JRadioButton group. When defining the radio buttons, it is telling me it doesn't like my setMnemonic syntax.

My code:

```
public JRadioButton mailRadio = new JRadioButton("Mail");
mailRadio.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_M);
```

It will show setMnemonic(int) in intellisense (or whatever the java version is called), but as soon as I accept that, mailRadio.setMnemonic is underlined for a syntax error. Hovering over it gives the error "Type mailRadio.setMnemonic not found." Compiling gives the error "Invalid method declaration; return type required."

As far as I know, I am attempting to do neither of these things. I haven't used Java in a long time, and I'm very rusty. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I have three JRadioButtons like this, and it will only show the error on the first one, until I comment it or remove then, then the error moves down to the next.

I am using JDeveloper 10.1.3.5, Java 1.5.0_06. Upgrading either is not an option at the moment, unfortunately.

Comment: You will probably find that going through the basic Java tutorials will help immensely with your Swing coding as without a basic understanding, Swing coding can be very frustrating indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing that you used `public` to declare the variable, I'm assuming the code snippet is inside a class declaration.

You can't use statements (and a method call such as `setMnemonic` is a statement) in a class declaration. You should call this method inside a constructor :

```
public class XXX {
    public JRadioButton mailRadio = new JRadioButton("Mail");

    public XXX() {
        mailRadio.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_M);
    }       
}
```

An alternative that looks more like what you initially tried to do is an initializer block:

```
public class XXX {
    public JRadioButton mailRadio = new JRadioButton("Mail");

    {
        mailRadio.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_M);
    }
}
```

But this is bad practice, I'm only mentioning it for completeness' sake.

More details [in the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Comment: Thank you. This was my problem, and thanks for the link to the doc. I'll this as the answer as soon as it lets me.